# flag to overwrite download url command

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, flags, getopts

I am pretty new to shell scripting and I have to add a flag (`getopts`) to my script where I can overwrite download url command if the script can't reach the url for any reason. For instance, if I add my flag then it won't terminate my script, I can choose to continue if url can't be reached.

Currently, I have

```
if "$?" -ne "0" then
echo "can't reach the url, n\ aborting"
exit
```

Now I need to add a flag through `getopts` where I can choose to ignore `"$?' - ne "0"` command,

I don't know how getopts works, I am pretty new to it. Can someone please help me on how to go about it?

Comment: See this link for documentation about getopts: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_getopts.htm

Comment: @DexterHuinda: That's simply [part of the Bash `man` page](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html#lbDB). Here is an excellent reference: [BashFAQ/035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one option, sometimes it's simpler to just check `$1`:

```
# put download command here
if (( $? != 0 )) && [[ $1 != -c ]]; then
    echo -e "can't reach the url, \n aborting"
    exit
fi
# put stuff to do if continuing here
```

If you're going to accept other options, some possibly with arguments, the `getopts` should be used:

```
#!/bin/bash
usage () { echo "Here is how to use this program"; }

cont=false

# g and m require arguments, c and h do not, the initial colon is for silent error handling
options=':cg:hm:' # additional option characters go here
while getopts $options option
do
    case $option in
        c  ) cont=true;;
        g  ) echo "The argument for -g is $OPTARG"; g_option=$OPTARG;; #placeholder example
        h  ) usage; exit;;
        m  ) echo "The argument for -m is $OPTARG"; m_option=$OPTARG;; #placeholder example
        # more option processing can go here
        \? ) echo "Unknown option: -$OPTARG"
        :  ) echo "Missing option argument for -$OPTARG";;
        *  ) echo "Unimplimented option: -$OPTARG";;
    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

# put download command here
if (( $? != 0 )) && ! $cont; then
    echo -e "can't reach the url, \n aborting"
    exit
fi
# put stuff to do if continuing here
```

Comment: So in the command line, i'd basically type sh myscript.sh -c cont? Please let me know

Comment: No, just `bash myscript.sh -c` or if you mark your script as executable (`chmod u+x myscript.sh`) and add a shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) as the first line, then you can do `./myscript.sh -c`

Comment: Sorry a quick question again,                                     what will this command do?                                                      if (( $? != 0 )) && ! cont; then
    echo -e "can't reach the url, \n aborting"
    exit
fi

Comment: @user1477324: You would put your download command right before that section. If the download is not successful and the `-c` option is not specified then output the message and exit. I've edited my answer to make it a little clearer.

Comment: for options, it would be :ch: or :c:h: ? and                          c  ) cont=true;;
h  ) usage; exit;;  is there a typo? i thought it would be h ) usage = exit;;  , what's the importance of 'h' here? sorry i am asking you way too many questions as i have no clue about getopts, but i appreciate your help so much.

Comment: @user1477324: The first colon signifies that silent error reporting is to be used and that the script will handle the errors. If you have additional colons they mean that the preceding option letter has a required argument. None do in this example. The 'h' is part of the `case` statement. It means that if `$option` contains an 'h' the following commands (until the `;;` should be executed. In the example, the commands are `usage` (to execute the `usage()` function which I have included a simple example) and `exit` which will exit the script. Please read the links that I included in my...

Comment: ...comment which is attached to your question for more information regarding `getopts` and try my example script and make some experimental changes to see how things work. Then please feel free to ask additional questions. If they are significant ones then they should be posted as completely new questions. I'm happy to help.

Comment: i followed your instructions and it doesn't seem to work for me somehow. It says if (( $? != 0 )) && ! **cont**; then" is not a valid command.

Comment: If i put **$cont**, it will keep on building whether i pass the flag or not.                                                              also **While Getopts has g:ch:m**. 'g' and 'm' are my other options on the script for other commands. Is my format right there?

Comment: @user1477324: That was a typo on my part. It should be `$cont`. I also forgot to include `cont=false` at the beginning. Please see my edited answer. No, the colon after the 'h' means that it needs an argument which is usually not the case for a help option. If you want `-m` to require an argument, put the colon after the 'm' instead. Also, you have `-g` requiring an argument if that's what you intend. You should include a colon at the beginning as I have show so the error handling is done properly.

Comment: @user1477324: Please see a couple of additional edits. If you find this answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. Upvotes are also welcome when your reputation is high enough to allow them.